# Draggable two-trees

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have to create two draggable trees to use it for upload files from one directory to another.

I found only an ExtJS example.

Does anyone know any similar example in jQuery?

[ExtJS example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/tree/two-trees.html)

[image]

Comment: Have you checked out the jQueryUI [sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists) interaction?

Answer (score 0):

check out [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/demo) and the [DND plugin](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/dnd) (drag-n-drop) it supports "foreign node" drops